# What does each number mean in MS Exchange 2010 OWA logs like CAS:90000/89411/1%

Tags: logging, exchange-server, outlook-web-app

Exchange 2010 OWA logs gives cr-url-query field. It includes part like following 
id=RgAAAABwGr6YDFgUQ7KYq4XnIgy9BwBJ594k4ywvSKbGXtN5DXVeAAAAiD2UAABJ594k4ywvSKbGXtN5DXVeAACAPzEeAAAJ&attcnt=1&attid0=BAAAAAAA&attcid0=image001.jpg%4001D08731.618E08F0&Initial+Budget>>Conn:1,HangingConn:0,AD:18000/18000/0%,CAS:90000/89411/1%,AB:18000/18000/0%,RPC:90000/89620/1%,FC:1000/0,Policy:DefaultThrottlingPolicy_8377b5d3-ee80-4915-9adc-c208e364e030

What does each  number mean in this log, especially following:  HangingConn:0,AD:18000/18000/0%,CAS:90000/89411/1%,AB:18000/18000/0%,RPC:90000/89620/1%,FC:1000/0   ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has absolutely nothing to do with programming.

Comment: They are the throttle usage statistics